# VS 2012 crash when I drag & drop classes form my solution to modeling project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, layer, modeling

I have visual studio 2012 ultimate solution with 4 projects ( 2 asp.net web forms, 1 console, 1 modeling project).

When I try to drag and drop ANY class form my solution explorer to a layer diagram in my modeling project, Visual Studio will stop working (Not Responding), and it will restart.

It will prompt me with the following message:
[image]

I did clean my solution, I did use the Visual Studio repair tool and nothing seems to correct this issue.

It also appears that the problem is related to my current solution only.

I created a test solution with few projects and the drag and drop functionality in a layer diagram works just fine.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this issue?

Clean/Reset values ?

Or check configurations somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue in VS 2012](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780034/add-class-to-layer-diagram-causes-crash). [According to Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e49850f-c0fb-4fab-9cfe-280cfcd42299/vs-bug-shown-as-fixed-in-ms-connect-but-how-can-i-fix-mine), it will be fixed in the next release of visual studio.

So, for VS 2012, there is no solution yet!